# How to target a url to display; block when default is display; none

Tags: javascript, jquery, display, target, expander

I inherited a site coded as below using jquery to designate an expander function to toggle major sections of the site open from default closed position (src expand images are little colored arrows). 
The sections are closed by default using “display: none;” and major sections have minor sections nested within them similarly toggled closed by default. 
The basic structure is below. 
The toggling on the site works fine – sections are closed by default but toggle between open and closed by clicking on headers. Now I would like to **provide URLs that will “display: block;” for the URL target using hashtags to subsections** (such as “mainpageurl#policy1” in the example below). The hashtags don’t work – the URL will simply go to the main page with all sections closed; will not open the target. 
Can anyone provide a simple solution? Is it possible without completely rewriting the code? Maybe this is a classic example of when not to use display; none?

```
<!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> --> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $jq(function() {
        $jq(".expander").click(function(){
          $jq(this).next('div').toggle();
        });
    });
```

```
<h1 class="expander"><src-arrow-image-here /><a> Policies</a></h1> 
 <div id="policies" style="display: block;">
<h2 class="expander"><src-arrow-image-here /><a> Policy 1</a></h2> 
<div  id="policy1" style="display: none;">
<p>Content - this is the first policy.</p> 
</div>
<h2 class="expander"><src-arrow-image-here /><a> Policy 2</a></h2>
<div  id="policy2" style="display: none;">
<p>Content - this is another policy.</p>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript solution would be parsing `window.location.hash` and jQuery `show()` targeted element after page content is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.hash` will get us the hash parameter from the URL, you can use it to toggle the relevant section like this:

```
const sectionID = window.location.hash; // will give sectionID with hashtag.

$(sectionID).show()
```

Comment: While your code may answer the author's question, you should add a brief explanation of what you have done and why

Comment: Thank you for your editing Revati and help @Alex. As might be apparent by now – I am not a coder and barely know what I am doing. I tried adding this to the header of code, but it didn’t work:
 <script>
const policy1 = window.location.hash;
$(policy1).show()
</script>
Any further tips you can give would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @nancy try to replace `$(policy1).show()`  with `$jq(policy1).show()` as it looks like you are using an old version of jquery.

Comment: @giuseppedeponte I thought my note made it enough clear, I will edit the post again with an explanation.

Comment: Sorry I cannot get it to work - @Liad thank you so much for trying to help!

Comment: @nancy are you sure the hash parameter is the sectionID?

Comment: thank you - I think so. If you look at my code example above, the section IDs in that are "policies" "policy1" and "policy2" - where it is written e.g. <a id="policy1">

Comment: @nancy yeah I see the problem, policyX are the Ids of the `a` elements(links) and not the `section div` you are trying to show. You should give the policyX Id to the `section div`. If you need me to adapt your html then quote me.

Comment: Wow thanks for that! I believe I am making progress! I now know (something about) the difference between <section> and <div> and what <a> is for (I believe I mentioned I am somewhat clueless in these matters?) I have partly succeeded. The hash #policy1 now returns the open section - but only if I open the parent "policies" section by default. I haven't figured out how to have the major section (policies) closed (not displayed) by default, and have the subsection (policy1 etc) open with the hash.

Comment: @nancy the problem is that your `policies` div contains all the other sections and is set to `display:none`, set it to `display:block` by default and it will fix that.And don't feel bad for asking questions, we all have been clueless at some point.  P.S if your problem is solved mark the answer

Comment: @nancy I have proposed an edit to your html.. see the fixes